# setTimeout() with jQuery don't work on Chromium

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I've got own gallery code like:

```
// Gallery
$(function() {
  var images = $('#gallery ul li img');
  var next = 0;
  var timer;
  var delay = 5000;
  images.click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('current')) return false;                   // Prevent from re-showing
    $('#gallery ul li.current').toggleClass('current');             // Change current highlighted photo
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');                        // to $(this)
    $('#gallery img#show-window').attr('src', $(this).data('src')); // Change viewed photo
    $('#gallery .panel h2').text($(this).attr('title'));            // Set title 
    $('#gallery .panel p').text($(this).attr('alt'));               // Set description
    next = $.inArray(this, images) + 1;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      images[next % images.length].click();
    }, delay);
  });
  images[0].click();
});
```

And if I run it on Chromium (Arch Linux 15.0.874.121 (Build 0 Linux)) it is't showing image until I click on any of the gallery previews and even then it isn't changing to next picture after 5s. It works on Firefox 8.0 and Opera 11.52.

Comment: Do some debugging. Is the click even even being called the first time? What about the second time? I think if you moved the scoping of "images" into the anonymous function call it might fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "doTimeout" function?

```
$.doTimeout( 'someid', 1000, function( state ){
             .alert( state ); // alert true in 1 second
             .}, true);
```

Comment: I've solved it. I should only add `$()` over `images[0]` and then it's worked. But thanks @brpyne.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me, but it seems a little redundant to do this with setTimeout programatically  clicking the next image when you can do this with [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).

```
function nextImage()
{
    // insert image selection logic here
}

$(function(){
    var imgDaemon = setInterval(nextImage(), 5000);
});
```

Comment: It wasn't problem with any of the `timeout` functions byt with unrecognised function `.click()`.